# I've found a MATLAB plot in a book and want to know which command the authors used for the plot

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I'm reading a book where the authors write that

[image: plot]

is a MATLAB plot of the approximation obtained by the method of lines for the finite difference approximation of the Nagumo equation $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}u=\varepsilon\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+u(1-u)(u-\alpha)$$ for $\varepsilon=1$ and $\alpha=1/2$ on $(0,1)$. The approximation is a set of vectors $u_{t_n}$ approximating $(u(t_n,x_1),\ldots,u(t_n,x_J))$ with $t_n=n\Delta t$.

Which MATLAB command did they use?

Comment: I guess that since you're reading the book (which is about Matlab applications) you must learn how to do it from it... Anyway, there's no command which plots you the solution right away. You need to construct a script which does it... Continue reading the book (by the way, you could mention its title... if you want someone to help). The code might be presented somewhere

Comment: @BeniBogosel Sorry, I don't want to know how to solve the problem. I want to know how they plot the solution, i.e. do they use a contour plot or something else?

Comment: This looks like a `contourf` plot with lots of contour levels, or a `surf`/`mesh` with the view modified to above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the plot you're after then it might go something like this. Suppose that $M$ is a matrix containing the discrete values of your function, found on a finite differences grid. If you have times from $0$ to $10$ and $n$ steps on the horizontal axis then the code might look something like

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,n),linspace(0,10,11));
surf(X,Y,M); view(2); shading interp; colormap gray;
```

Comment: In the book they've got a solution matrix `ut` which is `513 × 1001`, a space-vector `x` which is `513 × 1` and a time-vector `t` which is `1001 × 1`. I've tried to use `[X, Y] = meshgrid(t, x)` and `surf(X, Y, ut)`, but the plot is entirely black. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the graph is entirely black, then your ut contains only one value. Probably there may be a mistake in the computation of ut.

Comment: I've used the wrong parameters. It's working now! Thanks for your help. Can I swap the x and y-axis somehow?

Comment: If you need to swap axes just change the role of X and Y and transpose ut: surf(Y,X,ut')